# How to make admob always shows an ad on android?

Tags: android, admob

I know that there is only a certain fill rate that admob can fill. However I want to show something anyway, or it will make my UI inconsistent. I tried to enable the "house ad", but still sometimes the ad bar is not filled.

Is there a way to force admob to show some ads? I believe getting more ads displayed can only be a good thing for them. Otherwise, can I manually check if there is no ad returned? Thus I can replace the ad bar with my own decorating bar.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Admob will always show an ad if possible. And if it can't show a paid ad, it will show one of your house ads. However sometimes it still doesn't pop up so, like you said, you want to check if it appeared and if not, replace it with something else. Create a listener class that extends SimpleAdListener. Then override the onFailedToReceiveAd method like so:

```
@Override
            public void onFailedToReceiveAd(AdView adView)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onFailedToReceiveAd(adView);
                //Display your other view here.
            }
```

Check the LunarLander sample to get a better idea.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Although I still don't understand why AdMob doesn't take every possible chance to display ads...

Comment: It does take every possible chance, it's just that sometimes it fails to work for a number of different reasons. Glad I could help!